# Invalid datetime string when CAST As Date

Tags: sql, date, datetime, casting, google-bigquery

I have `Time` column in BigQuery, the values of which look like this: `2020-09-01-07:53:19` it is a STRING format. I need to extract just the date. Desired output: `2020-09-01`.

My query:

```
SELECT
    CAST(a.Time AS date) as Date
from `table_a`
```

The error message is: `Invalid datetime string "2020-09-02-02:17:49"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the `parse_datetime()`, then convert to a date.

```
with temp as (select '2020-09-02-02:17:49' as Time)
select 
  date(parse_datetime('%Y-%m-%d-%T',Time)) as new_date
from temp
```

Answer (score 1):

How about just taking the left-most 10 characters?

```
select substr(a.time, 1, 10)
```

If you want this as a `date`, then:

```
select parse_date('%Y-%m-%d', substr(a.time, 1, 10))
```

Comment: for the first query the error message is: `Unsupported LEFT function`. For the second one: `No matching signature for function DATE for argument types: STRING`

Comment: @Chique_Code . . . The `LEFT()` was a brief moment of wishful programming.  I did learn that `date()` doesn't take a string expression, even though I use constructs such as `date('2020-01-01')` all the time.  I guess the parser accepts a string constant, but not a string expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
select STR_TO_DATE('2020-09-08 00:58:09','%Y-%m-%d') from DUAL;
```

or to be more specific as your column do as:

```
select STR_TO_DATE(a.Time,'%Y-%m-%d') from `table_a`;
```

Note: this format is applicable where mysql is supported